# How to add zeros to single-digit time values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function

Below is a code that I'm working on. I changed it from 24-hour to a 12 hour format time by reading one of the answers that I found on this website. The only problem is that 5 minutes ago, the time was 2:5, and I want it to show 02:05. I'm not sure what exactly to change. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
function theClock12hour()
{
    function pad(n) {
        return (n < 10) ? "0" + n : n;
    }

    var time = new Date();
    var nHours = time.getHours();
    var nMins = time.getMinutes();

    if (nHours > 12) {
        nHours -=12;
    } else if (nHourse ===0) {
        hours = 12;
    }
    document.getElementById("hourbox").innerHTML = nHours;
    document.getElementById("minutebox").innerHTML = nMins;

    var nDay = time.getDate();
    document.getElementById("datebox").innerHTML = nDay;

    var nMonth = time.getMonth();
    if      (nMonth ==  0){ nMonth = 'JANUARY'; }
    else if (nMonth ==  1){ nMonth = 'FEBRUARY'; }
    else if (nMonth ==  2){ nMonth = 'MARCH'; }
    else if (nMonth ==  3){ nMonth = 'APRIL'; }
    else if (nMonth ==  4){ nMonth = 'MAY'; }
    else if (nMonth ==  5){ nMonth = 'JUNE'; }
    else if (nMonth ==  6){ nMonth = 'JULY'; }
    else if (nMonth ==  7){ nMonth = 'AUGUST'; }
    else if (nMonth ==  8){ nMonth = 'SEPTEMBER'; }
    else if (nMonth ==  9){ nMonth = 'OCTOBER'; }
    else if (nMonth == 10){ nMonth = 'NOVEMBER'; }
    else if (nMonth == 11){ nMonth = 'DECEMBER'; }

    document.getElementById("monthbox").innerHTML = nMonth;

    var nTday = time.getDay();
    if      (nTday == 0){ nTday='SUN'; }
    else if (nTday == 1){ nTday='MON'; }
    else if (nTday == 2){ nTday='TUE'; }
    else if (nTday == 3){ nTday='WED'; }
    else if (nTday == 4){ nTday='THU'; }
    else if (nTday == 5){ nTday='FRI'; }
    else if (nTday == 6){ nTday='SAT'; }

    document.getElementById("daybox").innerHTML = nTday;

    var nYear = time.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById("yearbox").innerHTML = nYear;

    timer = setTimeout("theClock12hour()",1000);
}
```

Comment: use the `pad(n)` function that is already in your code

Comment: @Downvoter - What is wrong with this question?  That the answer is obvious to you but not to the asker?

Comment: Just a quick tip, there's a library called moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) that is really good for date manipulation and formatting.

Comment: Also `else if (nHourse ===0)`, shouldn't that be nHours ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### To answer your question

Your code may do what you want if you add the pad function you have around nMins variable.

http://jsfiddle.net/queuehammer/T5R5C/

```
document.getElementById("minutebox").innerHTML = pad(nMins);
```

Also I noticed an issue in the nHours logic

```
if (nHours > 12) {
    nHours -=12;
} else if (nHourse === 0) {
    hours = 12;
}
```

The first line checks if nHours is less than 12 while the else if checks if nHours is equal to 0. Because 0 < 12 the second 'if' will not be reached in the case where you want to force nHours to be 12 instead of 0. There were some other minor updates but no other changes to the logic. See this code and the updated fiddle.

```
if (nHours > 12 && nHours != 0) {
    nHours -=12;
} else if (nHours == 0) {
    nHours = 12;
}
```

#### To add to the comment about Moment.js

I also wrote up the example using Moment. I have looked over other time libraries for my own and and I have settled on moment at this time.

http://jsfiddle.net/queuehammer/HhruW/

```
//More info at: http://momentjs.com/
document.getElementById("OurText").innerHTML = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

Comment: Thank you QueueHammer, you're a genius!

Comment: Hey man. I thought my problem was fixed but it's almost. It's midnight right now and it shows 00:21. How do I make it say 12:21? Thanks.

Comment: It's only for midnight, it's 9:20am and it shows 09:20am, the right format I want, but it's midnight is where it's wrong..

Comment: I found the issue. Select this as the answer and I can post another fiddle with some visual updates to the if/else logic.

Comment: Okay, I have selected that as the answer.

Comment: Thanks. So when using a large number of if/else statements and checking for a single value, the switch can be used an an alternative.
http://jsfiddle.net/queuehammer/T5R5C/3/

Comment: See the second code block in the answer. It was because in the original code "nHours > 12" was true for "0" and it was not reaching your else if. The jsfiddle link in the post was updated with the correct logic.
The link in my last comment is an example of how you can use a switch statement to replace the else if logic further down in the code.
Let me know if you dont see the update in the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/queuehammer/T5R5C/